# multiple variables in url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to pass variables to a method. for 
example:

```
http://localhost/project/user/username/posts/postid
```

and I want to start 'posts' method and have 2 variables, or an assoc table

```
$user = username;
$posts = postid;
```

if link is `http://localhost/project/user/username`
I want to start 'index' method and have variable
`$user = username`

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*pass your variable like this , URL structure should be like this :*

`http://localhost/base_folder/controller_name/method_name/username/post_id`

suppose ur controller name is `welcome` and method name is `index`, with username `shamer` and post id `4`; it will become like this :

`http://localhost/base_folder/welcome/index/shamer/4`

in anchor should be like this :

`<a href="<?=site_url('welcome/index/shamer/4');?>">your link</a>`

In `Welcome` controller get `username` and post `id` in your `index` method like this :

```
public function index($username, $post_id)
{
   echo $username;
   echo $post_id;
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

Comment: if my answer helps u pls don't forget to check it as green and do upvote also